# Mongoose: populate vs findById

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database-performance

what is the difference between populate and findById in performance? which one is faster?

Example

findById:

```
const comment = await Comment.findById(commentId);
const user = await User.findById(comment.userId);
```

populate:

```
const comment = await Comment.findById(commentId).populate('userId');
```

Comment: Reference of this sentence is yourself?? Theoretically populate method do the same thing that findById